# What does "It’s wholly backed up" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Here is a quote from [an article](https://us.yahoo.com/finance/news/how-to-protect-yourself-against-coronavirus-152101500.html) where an expert says that the measures taken to stop the spread of the current coronovirus are not up to par. What I don't understand in it is the very last phrase:

> The author also argued that official numbers are “grossly
>   underestimating” the true toll of infections.
>
> “They have a lag time in testing people; they don’t have enough test
>   kits; they have lines around the block, in Wuhan, of people trying to
>   get tested,” says Garrett. “**It’s wholly backed up**.”

What is wholly backed up? How is it backed up and by whom? And what kind of "backing up" exactly it is?

I know of two meanings of "back up". First one is "support" and the second one is "accumulate", but it looks like here is some other meaning.

Comment: @user105719. You are correct, of course! I’m not sure what made me leap in the wrong direction. I’ve deleted my comment.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie When I make those leaps, I just blame the drugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition here is very close to "accumulate," but it's an intransitive verb:

> ***back up***
>
> intransitive verb
>
> : to accumulate in a congested state
>
> *//traffic backed up for miles*
>
> source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/backup, Entry 2 of 2

"It" is referring to the process of testing people [for coronovirus].

"Wholly" means completely.

So "It's wholly backed up" is expressing that the testing process has slowed considerably, because of the factors in the middle of the quote:

> "...they don’t have enough test kits; they have lines around the block, in Wuhan, of people trying to get tested...”